# How to change a tkinter button's text while clicking in python

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-button

Here is my code:

```
buttons=[]
for i in range(100):
    buttons.append(Button(parent,text="0",command=lambda:[change(i)])
def change(i):
    buttons[i]["text"]="1"
```

but as finally, the i will go to 99, I could only change the last button no matter which button I clicked. So I wonder is there any good way to do so?

Comment: Seems like this is because of [Late Binding Closures](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures). Can you try `command=lambda i=i:[change(i)]` instead?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is very easy
Just change the command by below command

```
command = lambda i=i:change(i)
```

This will do the job for you.
Your solution not worked as expected because
python passes the last value of i
And hence to resolve this problem
The above command is the solution.
Here lambda is given argument(that is i) at the same time when each execution of loop is going and then that i
is passed to change function which is why it worked